# Thread error on ionic application when emulate android

Tags: android, multithreading, ionic-framework, genymotion, emulation

I am developing an Ionic App. It's running perfectly on iPhone, but when I emulate it with **GenyMotion**, it returns this error:

> Skipped 33 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread.

All the answers takes me to native Android code.

How to solve this through ionic code?

Comment: You are actually drawing/doing lot of things on Main thread. This may not be the same if you try to run on Good Physical Android smartphone.

Comment: Normally in emulators have little memory and graphics inrder to keep up, try the same running on an actualy device, you may not see it.

Comment: May be you can increase memory of your virtual device.